# deserialize existing xml into custom object

Tags: deserialization, xmlserializer, xml-deserialization

I have the following xml:

```
<state>
<groups>
    <group id='1' name='Basic Search Options'>
        <control name='Building' label='In' display='true' configurable='false'/>
        <control name='SearchType' label='For' display='true' configurable='false'/>
        <control id='1' default='C' name='Search By' label='By'>
            <option searchtype='C' searchmode='Cnumber' value='CNumber' label='C Number' display='true'/>
            <option searchtype='C' searchmode='crossrefnumber' value='CNumber1' label='Cross Reference Number' display='true'/>
            <option searchtype='P' searchmode=''  value='CaseNumber' label='P Name' display='true'/>
            <option searchtype='P' searchmode='' value='CaseNumber' label='A Name' display='false'/>
        </control>
    </group>
    <group id='2' name='Advanced Search Options'>
        <control name='Ctatus' label='C Status' display='true'/>
        <control name='DateFiled' label='Date Filed' display='true'/>
    </group>
</groups>
```

How would I de-serialize this into the following object? I dont want my xml to have the following tags "ArrayofGroup", instead the xml should have custom tags like mention above.

```
public class GroupOfControls
{
public int instanceId { get; set; }
public int GroupId { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public List<SearchControl> Group { get; set; }
}

public class SearchControl
{
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Label { get; set; }
public bool Display { get; set; }
public string Default { get; set; }
public List<SearchOption> SearchOptions { get; set; }
}

public class SearchOption
{
public string Value { get; set; }
public string Label { get; set; }
public bool Display { get; set; }
public string SearchMode { get; set; }
public string SearchType { get; set; }
}
}
```

Comment: Do you have an XSD file for the XML? I'm assuming you're using C# but which version? Also which version of .Net?

Comment: VS C# 2010 and .Net version: 4.0 - I dont have an XSD file.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have an XSD file, you need to create one from your XML. You can do this with the Visual Studio Command Line using the following command:

```
xsd myfilename.xml
```

Once you have an XSD file this should be easy enough.

I am working with Visual Studio 2010 (C#/.Net 4) and I would do this:

First I would make a new solution in Visual Studio:

[image: New Project]

Then you need to import the XSD file into your project by right clicking on your solution, and selecting `Add => Existing Item` and browsing to the XSD.

Once you have the XSD inside your project you need to launch the Visual Studio command prompt, use `cd` to navigate to your projects directory and then type the following command:

```
xsd myFilename.xsd /classes
```

This generates the C# class you are going to deserialize your XML into. Use the `Add Existing Item` dialogue to import this new class into your solution.

Next you add `using System.Xml.Serialization;` and `using System.IO;` to your using statements. Then use the following code to deserialize your XML to an object (assuming the XML validates against your XSD). The most recent XSD I could file I called `ResponseData` as shown below:

[image: SolutionExplorer]

With this in mind, my C# code is below:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace XML_Deserialization
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ResponseData myResponseData = new ResponseData();

            XmlSerializer mySerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ResponseData));
            StreamReader myStreamReader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\JMK\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\scratch\XML Deserialization\XML Deserialization\text.xml");
            myResponseData = (ResponseData)mySerializer.Deserialize(myStreamReader);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure you don't need to do
    `ResponseData myResponseData = new ResponseDate();`
Just
    `ResponseData myResponseData =         (ResponseData)mySerializer.Deserialize(myStreamReader);`